# Installed option not showing in Attributes Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

[image][image][image]

there no option for install or uninstall for view/button.

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: I think that got removed for view from xcode 6 already

Comment: nop there is this option "installed" in xcode 8. both are screen shot of xcode 8 for different mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An installed checkbox is related to size classes is your size classes enabled for that `storyboard`?

For Older Xcode, you can find this `Use size classes` checkbox in the first tab of Attribute Inspector.

For XCode 8.0 and grater you can find the new option `Use Trait Variations` checkbox in the first tab of Attribute Inspector.

see the screen shot:

[image][image]
[image]

Then & then you can see the Installed checkbox in the Attribute inspector.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: i got the idea.please check my screen shot again.

Comment: You need to check `Use Traits Variations` than & than you can get that Installed option. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Installed** option is very much available in *Attribute Inspector* in *XCode 8.1*, try changing your `UIButton` position, it won't show **Installed** option if it's not placed properly.